# Background Work does not work in the Foreach function?

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, progress-bar, backgroundworker

My app sends messages to the selected groups in the `CheckedListBox`. I want to use a `Progressbar` while the program sends the message.

```
foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) 
{
    if (item.ToString() == gi.name)             //don't read
    {
        if (txtBoxPath.Text == string.Empty)    //don't read
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                args["message"] = txtBoxStatus.Text;
                fb.Post(gi.id + "/feed", args);

                sCount = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < sCount; i++)
                {
                    backgroundWrkSendPOST.ReportProgress(100 / sCount); //****HERE****
                }
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERRO:" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            .......
```

Where: sCount (int): represents the number of checked items in the checked listbox.
So, following the Math rules, for each items that is selected {y} (items in the foreach function) should mulplicate for the 100% / {y}, it means, that the final should be 100%. But it seems that the foreach function does not read the background worked, and does not multiplicate.

Output when we debug:

[image]

Can someone help me? This progressbar should, at the end, stay in 100%.

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right you have 2 items checked (`sCount=2`) and you loop two times (`i<sCount`) calling `ReportProgress` with the same value (100/2).

The output is always 50 and so no surprise that the ProgressBar shows always 50

I would try to change your code in this way

```
sCount = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count;
// Supposing that you could access your ProgressBar in this point
pBar.Maximum = sCount; 
pBar.Minimum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sCount; i++)
{
    backgroundWrkSendPOST.ReportProgress(i); 
}
```